# How do I initialize this 2D array with null in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have made a 2-d array which will store references to objects of the children classes of parent class `Student`.

```
Student[][] a = new Student [5][4];
```

Now I want to initialize this array with `null`? How do I do it? Any trick to doing it at once? Also, I Wanted to know if it is possible to store references of children class in an array of Base class in Java?

I want to initialize all the values with `null`. Also, let's say some values are filled and then I want to overwrite the values with `null`. How do I do that?

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to do? `Student[][] a = null;` ? You have to be more precise. you probably want to initialse all values in the array with null, which would be done with nested for-loops.

Answer (score 5):

By default JAVA initialises the reference objects with null.

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways, choose the most priority for you.

```
Student[][] a = null; // reference to a equals null
Student[][] a = new Student[5][];  // {null, null, null, null, null}
Student[][] a = new Student[5][5];  // {{null, null, null, null, null}, {...}, ...}
```

For your purpose (from the comment), you could use [`Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29). For example,

```
for(Student[] array : a) Arrays.fill(array, null);
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j)
        a[i][j] = null;
```

> Also, I Wanted to know if it is possible to store references of children class in an array of Base class in Java?

Yes, that's possible. The process named upcasting (`SubStudent` is upcasted  to `Student`).

```
a[0][0] = new SubStudent();
a[0][1] = new Student();
```

Comment: if I fill the array with some values, and then if I want to overwrite the values in the entire array with NULL, then also I can use the above method?

Comment: @HarryLewis, I showed to you ways of initialization, if you want to change all values in  the array, you may use `Arrays,fill` or `a[i][j] = null` in `for` loops manually